# how to show an alert after validation but before submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have all of my validation code figured out but I'm not quite sure on how to code an alert to pop up before the form is submitted but after the validation is complete.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 8 Lab - JavaScript DOM and Arrays</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function validate()
    {
        var fName = document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value;//first name validation
        if(fName==null || fName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a first name.";
            return false;
        }


        var lName = document.forms["orderForm"].lastName.value;//last name validation
        if(lName==null || lName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a last name.";
            return false;
        }


        var address = document.forms["orderForm"].address.value;//address validation
        if(address==null || address=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML= "Please enter an address.";
            return false;
        }


        var city = document.forms["orderForm"].city.value;//city validation
        if(city==null || city=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML= "Please enter a city.";
            return false;
        }


        var pCodeCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;//postal code validation
        if(postalCode.value.match(pCodeCheck))
        {
            //do nothing
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML= "Please enter a valid postal code.";
            return false;
        }

                    // makes sure you cannot order a negative number of items
        var itemQTY = document.forms["orderForm"].widget1qty.value;
        if(itemQTY < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }


        var itemQTY2 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget2qty.value;
        if(itemQTY2 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }


        var itemQTY3 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget3qty.value;
        if(itemQTY3 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }

                    //makes sure there is at least one item ordered
        var wid1Qty = document.getElementById('widget1qty').value;
        var wid2Qty = document.getElementById('widget2qty').value;
        var wid3Qty = document.getElementById('widget3qty').value;
        if(wid1Qty + wid2Qty + wid3Qty == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML= "You must order atleast one item.";
            return false;
        }

    /*
                                // trying to send alert with the order total.
                                // not sure how to call it after the validation is done.
            var total1;         
            var total2;
            var total3:
            var total4;

            if(document.getElementById('widget1qty').value == 0)
            {
                total1 = 0;
            }

            else(document.getElementById('widget1qty').value != 0)
            {
                total1 = document.getElementById('widget1qty').value * 5;
            }


            if(document.getElementById('widget2qty').value == 0)
            {
                total2 = 0;
            }

            else(document.getElementById('widget2qty').value != 0)
            {
                total2 = document.getElementById('widget2qty').value * 15;
            }


            if(document.getElementById('widget3qty').value == 0)
            {
                total3 = 0;
            }

            else(document.getElementById('widget3qty').value != 0)
            {
                total3 = document.getElementById('widget3qty').value * 25;
            }


            total4 = (total1 + total2 + total3)
            alert('Your total is: $' + total4 + '.00');
            */
    }
</script>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <h2 class="center">Order Form</h2> <!-- action="processForm.html"       "javascript:void(0)" -->
    <form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="validate();" action="processForm.html">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
    <table>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="30"></td>
            <td id="firstNameError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="30"></td>
            <td id="lastNameError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30"></td>
            <td id="addressError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>City:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30"></td>
            <td id="cityError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Province:</td>
            <td><select name="province" id="province" size="1">
                    <option disabled>Select a province</option>
                    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                    <option value="QC">Québec</option>
                    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                    <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                    <option value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
                    <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
                    <option value="NWT">Northwest Territories</option>
                    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span>Postal Code:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" maxlength="6"></td>
            <td id="postalCoderror"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Order Information</legend>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Select your products:<br>
            <td>Widget #1&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget1qty" id="widget1qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$5.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Widget #2&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget2qty" id="widget2qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$15.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Widget #3&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="widget3qty" id="widget3qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$25.00/ea</strong></td>
                <td id="qtyError3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="itemQTY"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Shipping Type:</td>
            <td>Standard ($5.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeStandard" value="Standard" checked></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Express ($10.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeExpress" value="Express"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Overnight ($20.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeOvernight" value="Overnight"></td>
        </tr>

        </table>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit Order</legend>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="return validate();" value="Submit Order"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset Form"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>  
</body>
```

I just don't know how to code it to pop up after the validation is complete.

Comment: you can `return false;` or use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: We need to see your HTML as well.

Comment: `else` statements don't contain a conditional. You'll need to change those to `else if` statements...

Comment: i just added all of the JS and html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, you could put an`id = "myForm"`and then do this in javascript:

```
    function validateForm() {
var fName = document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value;//first name validation
        if(fName==null || fName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a first name.";
            return false;
        }


        var lName = document.forms["orderForm"].lastName.value;//last name validation
        if(lName==null || lName=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML= "Please enter a last name.";
            return false;
        }


        var address = document.forms["orderForm"].address.value;//address validation
        if(address==null || address=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML= "Please enter an address.";
            return false;
        }


        var city = document.forms["orderForm"].city.value;//city validation
        if(city==null || city=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML= "Please enter a city.";
            return false;
        }


        var pCodeCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;//postal code validation
        if(postalCode.value.match(pCodeCheck))
        {
            //do nothing
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML= "Please enter a valid postal code.";
            return false;
        }

                    // makes sure you cannot order a negative number of items
        var itemQTY = document.forms["orderForm"].widget1qty.value;
        if(itemQTY < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }


        var itemQTY2 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget2qty.value;
        if(itemQTY2 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }


        var itemQTY3 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget3qty.value;
        if(itemQTY3 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML= "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            return false;
        }

                    //makes sure there is at least one item ordered
        var wid1Qty = document.getElementById('widget1qty').value;
        var wid2Qty = document.getElementById('widget2qty').value;
        var wid3Qty = document.getElementById('widget3qty').value;
        if(wid1Qty + wid2Qty + wid3Qty == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML= "You must order atleast one item.";
            return false;
        }
        var total1;
        var total2;
        var total3;
        var total4;

        total1 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget1qty'].value * 5;
        total2 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget2qty'].value * 15;
        total3 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget3qty'].value * 25;
        total4 = (total1 + total2 + total3)
        alert('Your total is: $' + total4 + '.00');
        return;
    }
function startValidate(){
        validateForm();
        document.forms['orderForm'].submit();
}
```

Edit: 
Just add all the other info in the `validateForm()` function.
I did't seen it because I started my edit before you added the HTML and the other JS.

According to War10ck's post you should change this :

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" onsubmit="startValidate()" value="Submit Order">
```

Comment: You should consider firing the validation function in the `onsubmit` event. For more information, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onsubmit) reference.

Comment: unfortunately it redirects to the process page before the alert pops up. sorry for the trouble guys, I've been trying to figure it out for three hours lol

Comment: Then try replacing alert() with 
if(confirm('Your total is: $' + total4 + '.00. Press Ok to continue.'))
document.forms['orderForm'].submit();
..That should really stop the script in the right place

Answer (score 0):

You can make another function called FireOnSubmit and do something like this:

`

```
function FireOnSubmit(){
   if(validate()==true) alert(""form validated..is being redirected")
   else { 
          alert("invalid form data");
          return false;
   }

}
```

`

You can put FireOnSubmit on the onsubmit of the form instead of the validate function.

Also, you will need to return true or false from your validate function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all that JavaScript, this should work just as well.
The submit button cannot be clicked until all fields you pick have been filled.
Then a alert pops up with your message.

This Goes In The Head Section

```
<script>

function checkform()
{
var f = document.forms["testform"].elements;
var cansubmit=true;
for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
if (f[i].value.length==0) cansubmit=false;
}
if (cansubmit)
{
document
.getElementById('submit'
).disabled=false;
}
}
</script>
```

Here Is The Form. The Submit Button Is Disabled Until All Fields Are Filled.

```
<form name="testform">
<input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="First Name"required/><br>
<input type="text" onKeyup="checkform()" placeholder="Last Name" required/><br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" onclick="alert('Your Alert Here...')"/>
</form>
```